# Fallo en JOB al ejecutar paquete SSIS

Tags: ssis

He creado un JOB para ejecutar un paquete SSIS pero me da varios errores.

Si ejecuto el paquete manualmenten no falla pero a traves del JOB si.

A continuacion, se puede ver un pantallazo con los errores.

Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías asegurarte de lo siguiente:

1. ¿La cuenta de usuario que estas usando cuando lo ejecutás manual es la misma que ejecuta el agente?
2. ¿La cuenta de usuario que ejecuta el agente tienen permisos suficientes? (Acceso a la base de datos por ejemplo)
3. Si estás usando SQL Server 2008 o superior en un sistema de 64 bits, puede darte problemas no contar con un driver de 64 bits. En ese caso podrías verificar la opción **"Use 32-bit runtime"** en el tab "Execution options" dentro del paso del Job correspondiente. (No tengo instalado en español, pero seguro te darás cuenta cómo es en ese entorno)

Te recomiendo un libro, si es que no lo has visto todavía. Tiene varias FAQ sobre SQL Server SSIS que te pueden ser útiles.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlforum/2011/06/09/sql-server-community-faqs-ebook-download/

Comment: Muchas gracias,

El problema estaba en el punto 3 que comentas.

No sabia de la existencia de ese libro, le echaré un ojo.

Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Me alegro de haber colaborado. Marcalo como respuesta correcta cuando puedas. Saludos